# Is a SQL Azure Table similar to an Azure Cosmos DB Container?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using the Cosmos DB SQL API. But I am confused how to migrate my existing SQL DB into Azure Cosmos DB.

Is an SQL Table similar to a Cosmos DB Container. Or do we need to store all SQL table data into one container with different Partition keys?

Comment: See how this works for you https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1266054/Migrate-Data-from-SQL-Server-to-Azure-Cosmos-DB

Comment: no, they are not similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosmos DB Data Migration tool can be used to import data from SQL Server into Cosmos DB. Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQL)

A Cosmos DB Container is not similar to a SQL Server Table. You can import data from multiple tables in a database into a single Cosmos DB container.

Comment: Thanks BOB for your comment, Can you pleases help to understand migration Azure SQL to Cosmos DB. what I understood is, A row in SQL table is like a Document(Item) in Cosmos DB, all the SQL tables row we should migrate COSMOS DB as a items(1 SQL table row = Document or item in Cosmos DB), How can I group a table data in COSMOS DB, do we need to add table name as well in a created Document in COSMOS or partition key is for segregation ?

Comment: @AkhilTyagi for simpler tables with no relation, a sql table row can be converted directly into a cosmos db json document. You can add an additional property called type to identify object type (eg. type = Customer if its from Customer table). For complex types with relational data in multiple tables, like Customer Addresses, you need to either embed/reference Address object. You can refer this microsoft link for a detailed understanding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data

Comment: Thanks a million @BOB, your comments helped a lot to understand.

Comment: I would say that logically Container *is* similar to table and item to row. I mean, of course you can put multiple relations (related rows across different tables) into one item in container, but it is also possible to do migration data to other sql-based database making single table there from multiple tables in source database. So technically you can do migration to containers as tables and items as rows, just having multiple relations between them would make querying more difficult, so it is important to consider joining some tightly related tables into one container.

Answer (score 1):

Do not be fooled by the name. The Cosmos DB SQL API does not allow you to work with Cosmos DB as though it were a relational database.

It is fundamentally a JSON document database, for storing items in a container. It is schema-less. Whilst you can import data after a fashion (as @Bob linked), you don't end up with relational tables - it's all JSON documents.

The SQL API allows you to use a SQL like syntax to query the JSON structure - the semantics however, are all based on these hierarchically structured documents, allowing you to return arrays of the JSON documents or projections of them.

*Queries always run in the context of a specific container*.

You can't JOIN across documents for example - you [use JOINs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join) to self-join *within* individual documents. There is [basic aggregation across documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-aggregates), and [some limited grouping functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by).

The semantics are very different from SQL Azure; you need to think differently.

Comment: Thanks James for your comment, Can you pleases help to understand migration Azure SQL to Cosmos DB. what I understood is, A row in SQL table is like a Document(Item) in Cosmos DB, all the SQL tables row we should migrate COSMOS DB as a items(1 SQL table row = Document or item in Cosmos DB), How can I group a table data in COSMOS DB, do we need to add table name as well in a created Document in COSMOS or partition key is for segregation ?